# Can I find my own deleted answers which don't show up in the "Deleted Recent Answers" list

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I was going to make a post on my website on an answer I gave to a question once about doing a loop in in PHP but without using a loop (in which my answer was to use recursion). I went to my list of answers, sorted by newest but I can't find it. I do recall the question getting downvoted so I suspect that the OP might have deleted it as I was sure that another answer was selected as accepted. I checked my "Deleted Recent Answers" list yet it doesn't appear there so the question probably wasn't deleted recently.

Looking at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) which comes up in the similar questions list as I was typing this, the question is a feature request made years ago and the answers are just showing why or why not we should not have the list of our deleted posts and was made before we have "Deleted Recent Answers" list.

So I would like to know if I am able to find my own answers that were deleted which don't appear in the "Deleted Recent Answers".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[If you have 10k on the site, you can use `deleted:1` in a search to find *your* deleted posts](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users) (it will not show you others'). Otherwise, well, good luck finding it in a cache somewhere. There's no provision for finding older deleted posts without having at least moderator tools privileges.

If it's important, consider asking a ♦ mod to find it for you. (For example, this is sometimes done to help question-banned users.)

Comment: If i was lacking 10k could i get someone else who does to do the search for me?

Comment: @Memor-X: Someone else with 10k can't search for your posts, and moderators often have other things to do. Still, you can always *ask*.

Comment: So i assume that means Mods can but it depends if they have the time to right?

Comment: @Memor-X: Yup. On smaller sites they'd probably be happy to; on larger sites they may be considerably less eager.

Answer (score 1):

Google has aggressive caching, which sometimes isn't cleared when content is deleted.

You can use this for your advantage, e.g. using [this search](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:stackoverflow.com+%22Memor-X%22+answered), I found two deleted answers of yours: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522255/447356), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39585413/447356). I went only through first three pages, you can go over more and probably find what you're looking for. If you remember key words from your answer, it might help as well.